# Change selected Text BackColor in TextBox

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I was wondering how to achieve custom backcolors for selected text in a TextBox. By default, it uses windows's standard color for selected text (light blue). Since I'm using skinned text editors that are based on the winforms TextBox and the TextBox doesn't expose any properties to change the color, I was wondering if there are any other ways to change this system default color on an application level?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps...

```
public class MyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
        private const int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

        public MyTextBox()
        {
            this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.myTextBox_TextChanged);

        }

        private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]    
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);    
            // Listen for operating system messages.
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT:
                    PaintEventArgs pe = new PaintEventArgs(this.CreateGraphics(),this.RectangleToScreen(this.ClientRectangle));
                    this.OnPaint(pe);
                    break;
            }

        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
    // call base.OnPaint(pe);
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
            g.Clear(this.BackColor);
            string s = this.Text.Substring(0,this.Text.Length/2);
   // provide a object with how to split your string with colors
            string s1 =  this.Text.Substring(this.Text.Length/2);
            SizeF sf = g.MeasureString(s,this.Font);
            g.DrawString(s,this.Font,new SolidBrush(Color.Red),0,0);

            g.DrawString(s1,this.Font,new SolidBrush(Color.Black),sf.Width,0);
        }
    }
```